# Select latest record of consecutive rows containing same value SQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, duplicates

I have a programme running a ping to a set of machines every hour and storing the result of that ping (whether that computer is connected of not) in a table called `machine_ping_data`.

[This is the structure of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJEOI.png)

I am trying to get the latest consecutive records of each machine where the `status` is successful "SUCC". By consecutive I mean that they can get interrupted by a record of another `machine_id` but not by a record of the same `machine_id` with a different `status` (UNK, FAIL).
Also, when I say latest I mean there can be no more recent records for that `machine_id` with a `status` other than "SUCC". I hope this is clear.

[This is an example of the data I have in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdlkA.png)

The code I have so far is the following:

```
    SELECT machine_id, status, TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, MIN(insert_date), MAX(insert_date)) AS durationFROM (
        SELECT
        *
        , @groupNumber := IF(@prev_machine_id != machine_id OR @prev_status != status, @groupNumber + 1, @groupNumber) AS gn
        , @prev_machine_id  := machine_id
        , @prev_status := status
        FROM machine_ping_data
        , (SELECT @groupNumber := 0, @prev_machine_id  := NULL, @prev_status := NULL) var_init_subquery
        ORDER BY machine_id, insert_date DESC
    ) sq
    WHERE status = "SUCC"
    GROUP BY gn, machine_id, status
```

It does group up the consecutive results, but not just the latest ones, and it obtains the latest record for a particular `machine_id` regardless of the `status` being "SUCC" or not.
I have tried using unions also, but haven't gotten anywhere.

Any help or advices will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

start by reducing your problem to the core: The selection of the latest consecutive successful pings.

This can be done by using only a data table with three columns: `(machine_id INT, insert_date INT, status ENUM("SUCC", "FAIL"))`.

For this problem, I found the following solution:

```sql
SELECT C.machine_id, C.insert_date
  FROM data AS C
  WHERE C.status = "SUCC"
  AND (
    C.insert_date > ANY ( -- C.insert_date is later than the latest failure which occurred before the latest success.
      SELECT max(A.insert_date) AS LATEST_FAILURE_BEFORE_LATEST_SUCCESS
          FROM data AS A JOIN data AS B
          ON (A.machine_id = B.machine_id AND A.status != "SUCC" AND B.status = "SUCC" AND A.insert_date < B.insert_date)
          GROUP BY A.machine_id HAVING A.machine_id = C.machine_id
      )
    OR NOT EXISTS ( -- corner case NO_PRECEDING_FAILURES
      SELECT 1 FROM data AS D 
        WHERE D.machine_id = C.machine_id
        AND D.status != "SUCC"
    )
  );
```

I guess the complicated part is the inner `SELECT` where I join data with itself and select the `LATEST_FAILURE_BEFORE_LATEST_SUCCESS`. Here, I make use of the fact that the latest consecutive records of successful pings (usually) have failures which precede them. I select the latest fa

Full script with test cases:

```sql
DROP DATABASE example;
CREATE DATABASE example;
USE example;

CREATE TABLE data (
    machine_id INT,
    insert_date INT,
    status ENUM("SUCC", "FAIL")
);

-- Test cases with different machines
INSERT INTO data (machine_id, insert_date, status) VALUES
-- 0. a machine which has sequences of FAIL - SUCC
(0, 4, "FAIL"),
(0, 3, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(0, 2, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(0, 1, "FAIL"),
(0, 0, "FAIL"),
-- 1. a machine which has sequences of FAIL - SUCC - FAIL
(1, 4, "FAIL"),
(1, 3, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(1, 2, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(1, 1, "FAIL"),
(1, 0, "FAIL"),
-- 2. a machine which has sequences of FAIL - SUCC - FAIL - SUCC
(2, 7, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(2, 6, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(2, 5, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(2, 4, "FAIL"),
(2, 3, "SUCC"),
(2, 2, "SUCC"),
(2, 1, "FAIL"),
(2, 0, "FAIL"),
-- 3. a machine which has sequences of FAIL - SUCC - FAIL - SUCC - FAIL
(3, 9, "FAIL"),
(3, 8, "FAIL"),
(3, 7, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(3, 6, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(3, 5, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(3, 4, "FAIL"),
(3, 3, "SUCC"),
(3, 2, "SUCC"),
(3, 1, "FAIL"),
(3, 0, "FAIL"),
-- 4. a machine which has sequences of SUCC - FAIL
(4, 2, "FAIL"),
(4, 1, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(4, 0, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
-- 5. a machine which has sequences of SUCC - FAIL - SUCC
(5, 5, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(5, 4, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(5, 3, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(5, 2, "FAIL"),
(5, 1, "SUCC"),
(5, 0, "SUCC"),
-- 6. a machine which has sequences of SUCC - FAIL - SUCC - FAIL
(6, 7, "FAIL"),
(6, 6, "FAIL"),
(6, 5, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(6, 4, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(6, 3, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(6, 2, "FAIL"),
(6, 1, "SUCC"),
(6, 0, "SUCC"),
-- 7. a machine which has only FAIL
(7, 2, "FAIL"),
(7, 1, "FAIL"),
(7, 0, "FAIL"),
-- 8. a machine which has only SUCC
(8, 2, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(8, 1, "SUCC"), -- TARGET
(8, 0, "SUCC"); -- TARGET

SELECT C.machine_id, C.insert_date
  FROM data AS C
  WHERE C.status = "SUCC"
  AND (
    C.insert_date > ANY ( -- C.insert_date is later than the latest failure which occurred before the latest success.
      SELECT max(A.insert_date) AS LATEST_FAILURE_BEFORE_LATEST_SUCCESS
          FROM data AS A JOIN data AS B
          ON (A.machine_id = B.machine_id AND A.status != "SUCC" AND B.status = "SUCC" AND A.insert_date < B.insert_date)
          GROUP BY A.machine_id HAVING A.machine_id = C.machine_id
      )
    OR NOT EXISTS ( -- corner case NO_PRECEDING_FAILURES
      SELECT 1 FROM data AS D 
        WHERE D.machine_id = C.machine_id
        AND D.status != "SUCC"
    )
  );

-- Should return:
-- machine_id   insert_date
-- 0    3
-- 0    2
-- 1    3
-- 1    2
-- 2    7
-- 2    6
-- 2    5
-- 3    7
-- 3    6
-- 3    5
-- 5    5
-- 5    4
-- 5    3
-- 6    5
-- 6    4
-- 6    3
-- 8    2
-- 8    1
-- 8    0

DROP DATABASE example;
```

Comment: It didn't work, ended up having to reboot the system because this query crashed the server :/

Comment: @Chewaka10 Is this question still relevant for you? If so, I could help you with debugging the problems with my proposed solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think given the complexity of what you are trying to achieve, you are better off keeping the sql statement simple:

SELECT `insert_date`, `machine_id`, `status` FROM `machine_ping_data` ORDER BY `insert_date` DESC

Then using PHP/whatever you are calling the sql query from to process the data

So assuming PHP this code below would get you, per machine, the dates going back of each successful ping until the most recent not-successful.

```
$sql = "SELECT `insert_date`, `machine_id`, `status` FROM `machine_ping_data` ORDER BY `insert_date` DESC";
$db = (however you establish connection to your sql database...)
$res = $db->query($sql);
$machines = array();
while($r = $res->fetch_object())
{
  if(!isset($machines[$r->machine_id]))
  {
    $x = new stdclass;
    $x->history = array();
    $machines[$r->machine_id] = $x; 
  }

  $x->history[] = $r;
  if($r->status!="SUCC")
  {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Then the first entry in the "history" array for each machine is your latest success, and the last entry your latest failure for that machine.

In my experience it's better to keep sql queries as simple as possible and process data afterwards; this also reduces the load on the sever.